# Express routing to search results

Tags: javascript, express

Got a real newbie question here.  So i'm building an events page in which I'd like to filter results by date input (standard html form).  I've made this a get request with the following routing:

```js
app.get("/eventByDate/:date", async (req, res) => {
    const d = req.params.date;
    const data = await Event.find({ date: d });

    if (data) {
        res.render(`./events/eventByDate`, { data });
        
    } else {
        console.log("THERE IS NO DATA");
    }
});
```

`EventByDate` is its own page, and I can access the relevant stuff by manually typing, for example, http://localhost:3000/eventByDate/2021-01-20

But as it is just now, the form submit takes me there but with the query string in the title, i.e. http://localhost:3000/eventByDate/?date=2021-01-20

Does anyone have a solution to this?  My initial idea was to try to remove the query string but this seems a little inelegant, so I'm sure there is a simpler way that I'm completely missing?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use POST instead of GET and move the parameters into the request body. But in many cases the current behavior is better. The user can copy the URL and it already contains the parameters. The user can store it as a bookmark or send it to a colleague.

Comment: It worked! thanks so much for the suggestion Thomas, I was really banging my head against the wall with this one